# Laravel9 - faker->image (no me descarga imagenes)

Tags: laravel, descarga, faker

tengo el siguiente problema... Tengo un proyecto en laravel9 y usando seeder y factori pienso llenar con datos falsos usando faker de laravel, en mi tabla tengo un campo imagen, pero lo raro es que cuando ejecuto php artisan migrate:fresh --seed las imagenes se descargan pero después de terminar el proceso de migración las imágenes se borran...
mi codigo es el siguiente:
CursoFactory.php
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y también ya modifique el archivo image de faker
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como escribí las imágenes se descargan pero luego dela migración se borran... estoy trabajando en windows10.

Comment: ¿Para que necesitas descargar las imágenes? ¿No es más sencillo guardar una URL a la imagen?